# Image thumbnails for Facebook share a link

Tags: html, css, facebook, image

Everytime I share a link on facebook from my site, http://reviewsie.com, the twitter thumbnail is selected as the image thumbnail.  (This also happens in pinterest and some of my ad tools.) How do I make a certain image stand out and get selected correctly?

Answer (score 7):

You need to set this meta tag in your head

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourdomain.com/image.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

you **need to use** the [**Open Graph Protocol**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/).

**To check** how Facebook sees your page, use the URL Checker tool at:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

---

for your own example, [check the tool with your url](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://reviewsie.com)

and you can find that you are not using the OGP and for such, it simply randomly selects one picture.

and it reminds you about it:

> Inferred Property:    The **og:image** property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags

Answer (score 0):

If it's still **showing old thumbnail**, you need to refresh it on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Enter your web site link and **debug**. After that you'll see **'Scare again'** button there.